# Function definition in case of different type of arguments?

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple program in which I have defined a function which accepts certain type of argument , now new requirement I got has same procedures to be done which I had already in written in earlier function , but this time it should on different type of argument.I am not able to call straight way this same function for two different types of arguments. So my question is how I should modify my function to behave in such a way. I am hoping that it is possible. I would like something as ,I have function like `Sum(int 1,int j)` now I would like to use same function for `double` type arguments.

Comment: Read up on overloading; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called overloading. What you can do is simply write two functions:

```
public double Sum(int 1, int j)

public double Sum(double 1, double j)
```

And your program will call the appropriate one based on the arguments you pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple with generics

```
T Sum<T>(T i,T j) { ... }
```

However, you won't be able to do `i+j` or anything, so it depends.

Comment: Well, your last sentence makes this suggestion probably very useless for this purpose :)

Comment: @Joey true but in general, it is a very good alternative to overloading if you can constrain `T`, so probably worth mentioning

Comment: @psubsee2003: the key point in your comment is `if you can constrain` and no you can't constraint on numeric type

Comment: @sll I know, but I was speaking in generalities.... can you add I add j in this context no, but can you use generics as an alternative to overloading.  I didn't necessarily say it was the right answer for this specific question related to `Sum` but I think it is a valid answer in response to the title.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you define a method with double as parameter type and later you can call it for integer values as well.

```
private double Sum(double a, double b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

and later you can call it like:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int Sum = (int) Sum(a,b);
```

Since an integer can be passed to a double type parameter. But if your method involves complex calculation then you are better of with multiple overloads of the Sum method with different types.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer so far. Most numeric types get implicitly converted to double, so a method accepting double (plus maybe an overload accepting decimals) would accept all other types too, but this approach opens your code to subtle and not-so-subtle issues with the accuracy of floating points operations.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a new method with the same amount of parameters but different types.

```
public Int32 Sum(Int32 i, Int32 j)
{
    return i + j;
}

public Double Sum(Double i, Double j)
{
    return i + j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET there is no type encompassing different numeric types. So you need two overloads of the same method, one that takes `int` arguments, one that takes `double` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a method that takes `int` parameters

```
public int Sum(int val1,int val2)
{
    return val1 + val2;
}
```

Now you need  a method that takes `doubles`:

```
public double Sum(double val1,double val2)
{
    return val1 + val2;
}
```

If you want a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which supports all "numeric" types you can have  a look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33617/Arithmetic-in-Generic-Classes-in-C

Answer (score 0):

You can write **GENERIC METHODS** for different datatypes.
check this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
Look more into this link. It shows how o create a function that can handle several datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 2, b = 3;
        double c = 2.345, d = 3.45;
        object inta = a, intb = b;
        object doublec = c, doubled = d;
        Console.WriteLine(Sum(inta, intb).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Sum(doublec, doubled).ToString());

public object Sum(object a, object b)
    {
        object sum = null;
        if (a.GetType().ToString() == "System.Int32" && b.GetType().ToString() == "System.Int32")
        {
            sum = Convert.ToInt32(a.ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(b.ToString());
        }

        if (a.GetType().ToString() == "System.Double" && b.GetType().ToString() == "System.Double")
        {
            sum = Convert.ToDouble(a.ToString()) + Convert.ToDouble(b.ToString());
        }
        return sum;

    }
```

Comment: Looking at some of your past answers on other questions, I think you should try to include some more explanation of your code.  You have a couple of answers where you've only pasted code without any description of what it is doing or why it addresses the question.  The idea of SO is not just to provide solutions, it is to answer questions and be a repository of those questions and answers.